# fluent-plugin-elasticsearch: logstash_format true not working

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I am trying to implement this:
http://www.tipstuff.org/2014/01/Postfix-log-centralize-and-analysis-in-realtime-with-fluentd-elasticsearch-and-kibana-part-4.html

I have everything working with this configuration:

```
<match mail.info>
  type elasticsearch
  log_level debug
  index_name postfix_mail
  type_name postfix_mail
</match>
```

But when I add logstash_format true, it does not work. I desperately need timestamp in my ES index to get Kibana to work as desired.

```
<match mail.info>
  type elasticsearch
  log_level debug
  index_name postfix_mail
  type_name postfix_mail
  logstash_format true
</match>
```

I tried to add verbose logging in td-agent init script (-vv option), but I don't get anything of value there.

Any inputs to resolve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

in your match block, I'm not seeing any details for the elasticsearch server. maybe add that?

docs are here:
https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch